# switching language app with the same localized button

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I'm developing an iOS app with two languages. 
I localized the main storyboard for each language and now I'm trying to switch between languages using the same button (toggled button text).

I found many codes for changing the app language with buttons for each one like 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872222/ios-change-language-for-user-via-buttons) and [Advance-Localization-in-ios-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032207/how-to-change-application-language-on-run-time-using-two-button-in-iphone-sdk) but I don't know how to reload the storyboard with its .strings depending on the selected language in the button.
Any help please? thanks

[image: localized Main.storyboard]
[image: English strings file]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of how your localized strings files and storyboards are organized? I need it to tell more relevant answer

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added the screenshots of storyboard and strings file.

Comment: @Mane_87 .  i am new to localisation . i am working 3 different languages how can in change the language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that you can't use `Main.strings` files. You will end up moving all localisable texts in the storyboard to `Localizable.strings` and load the them from there using a method like `NSLocalizedString(key, comment)`.

Here is a [Working sample project](https://github.com/dobaduc/SO-32606991) on GitHub. It works as in the screenshot below:

[image]

Complete code for the demo view controller

```
#import "ViewController.h"

//--------------- Modify NSBunle behavior -------------
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface CustomizedBundle : NSBundle
@end

@implementation CustomizedBundle
static const char kAssociatedLanguageBundle = 0;

-(NSString*)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key
                            value:(NSString *)value
                            table:(NSString *)tableName {

    NSBundle* bundle=objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kAssociatedLanguageBundle);

    return bundle ? [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName] :
    [super localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName];
}
@end

@implementation NSBundle (Custom)
+ (void)setLanguage:(NSString*)language {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle], [CustomizedBundle class]);
    });

    objc_setAssociatedObject([NSBundle mainBundle], &kAssociatedLanguageBundle, language ?
                             [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]] : nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
@end

//--------------- Demo ---------------------------------
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL usingArabic;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self localizeTexts];
}

- (void)localizeTexts {
    self.label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"explanation_message", nil);
    [self.button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"language_switch_title", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}


- (IBAction)switchLanguageTouched:(id)sender {
    _usingArabic = !_usingArabic;
    NSString *targetLang = _usingArabic ? @"ar" : @"en";

    [NSBundle setLanguage:targetLang];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:targetLang forKey:@"selectedLanguage"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [NSBundle setLanguage:targetLang];

    [self localizeTexts];
}

@end
```

Your Localizable files will look like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.
Happy coding!

**Edit**: 
Without calling a method like 'localizeTexts' in the example above to 'refresh' the text value being displayed, it's impossible to reflect the currently selected language. The object is in memory so you must recreate or update its value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's OK for the Main.strings files but I'm asking if it's possible to change the language of the whole view and the rest of the application instead of setting all the components like the label and the button in localizeTexts method in your example? Thank you

Comment: Let's simplify your problem like this: how to reload 1 button text after switching language? The answer is: Without calling a method to 'refresh' the text value being displayed, it's impossible to reflect the currently selected language. The object is in memory so you must recreate or update its value.

Comment: Sorry but my problem isn't in the button but I should set all the application on the selected language. It means reloading the storyboard with the appropriate strings file. I tried many ways but I still stuck (like adding    ` [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];` and this code [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496404/how-to-get-localised-storyboard-strings-after-switching-to-language-at-runtime-i )